# Android Spinner listener if tap outside of dropdown

Tags: android, spinner, listener

I have a Spinner, user tap on it and drop down list appears, what if user tap outside of the control area? Is there any event listener for this case?

Like this:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/uv0qqhflhl6ro9p/spinner_tap.png

Update:
Or, how do know if the dropdown dismissed, but no item selected.

Thank you!

Comment: In the onClick maybe use a switch case, you switch all the view of your activity and manage de default field (= whene you don't click on a known view)

Comment: Could you please show an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example :

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.btn1 : 
                    //Do stuff
                    Break;
                case R.id.btn2 : 
                    //Do stuff
                    Break;
                default:
                    // Here manage the click for "no view clicked"
                    Break;
        }
    }
```